# Boot alternates between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot

I am using HP laptop. I have dual OS on the only drive (an HDD), Ubuntu 18.04 LTS along with Windows 10. My laptop boots alternatively in both OS.

While is restart laptop from Windows 10, at startup Grub is loaded and default OS is Ubuntu. When I restart from Ubuntu, after restart Grub is not loaded and directly Window is loaded.

I don't have any problem with this, F9 Key is always handy to choose the boot option, but this is something i am not getting, so want to know the actual reason of this behavior.

Result of `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 21 MiB, 22003712 bytes, 42976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 132 KiB, 135168 bytes, 264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 140 MiB, 146841600 bytes, 286800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 89.1 MiB, 93429760 bytes, 182480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 82 MiB, 86011904 bytes, 167992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 44.2 MiB, 46325760 bytes, 90480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 3.3 MiB, 3411968 bytes, 6664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 54.5 MiB, 57151488 bytes, 111624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 68C1D80E-6599-43CA-BB65-D996726E3B10

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2      923648    1128447    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1128448    1161215     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     1161216  499445759 498284544 237.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   499445760 1023733759 524288000   250G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  1023733760 1543921663 520187904   248G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7  1543921664 1953523711 409602048 195.3G Linux filesystem




Disk /dev/loop8: 156.7 MiB, 164290560 bytes, 320880 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 140.7 MiB, 147501056 bytes, 288088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 8.5 MiB, 8941568 bytes, 17464 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 1.6 MiB, 1691648 bytes, 3304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 12.2 MiB, 12804096 bytes, 25008 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 956 KiB, 978944 bytes, 1912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: I've never heard of this behavior before... But it takes my interest.

Comment: Do you have two drives, or just one? Please run `fdisk -l` in a Linux terminal. copy the result, click [edit],, and paste the result into your question.

Comment: @K7AAY I have only one Hard Drive of 1 TB.

Comment: Please run `fdisk -l` in a Linux terminal. copy the result, click [edit], and paste the result into your question.

Comment: Check which bootloader you have in EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi (compare the size to grubx64.efi, shimx64.efi, and bootmgfw.efi.  Probably it's Microsoft's bootmgfw.efi, so a device boot is Windows, but the EFI preference is Ubuntu.